# problema con require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

en este programa presenta una pagina web que no puede cargar, estoy usando xamp y el buscar el en log me sale el siguiente error:

[Tue Mar 29 13:17:38.883174 2022] [php7:error] [pid 4004:tid 1852] [client ::1:62497] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\fondoaraucoacercaredes\system\core/CodeIgniter.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\fondoaraucoacercaredes\index.php on line 327, referer: http://localhost/

en la linea 327 sale lo siguiente:
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
por lo que he leido hay un problema con el punto .htaccess que en este caso es el siguiente:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        #Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

y este es el error que me se muestra al intentar acceder a la pagina:
Esta página no funciona
localhost no puede procesar esta solicitud en este momento.
HTTP ERROR 500

no he podido encontrar solucion a esto, espero que alguien sepa algo, muchas gracias.
pd: estoy usando el framework codoIgniter version 3 y php version 7.4.28

Comment: ¿esa ruta existe?  `C:\xampp\htdocs\fondoaraucoacercaredes\system\core/CodeIgniter.php` ¿o está en otra parte?

Comment: ahora que lo veo la ruta si existe, pero el CodeIgniter.php es lo que no está.